# Can I connect to Azure blob Storage using SAS token in Pig Script

Tags: apache-pig, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

I want to Load data from Azure Blob Storage and write same to a destination path of Azure Blob Storage account using Pig Script.

The container is accessed via SAS token.

So, how do I connect to AzureBlobStorage using Pig script.

Any help, highly appreciated

Thank you..

Comment: From Blob to Blob? What is the pig script doing? I assume a copy activity isn't an option.

Comment: Yes..from Blob to Blob copy activity.Pig script needs to copy data from one source blob to destination blob location. The storage account will have SAS token generated. So, the Datasource to be created in Pig script will have a URL with SAS token generated in it..

Comment: Yes ok. But what is the pig script doing? What I'm getting at is do you need the pig script or is there a work around that doesn't require the SAS token.